# Calculate time duration while iterating on the same column

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by

Would it be possibile to calculate the daily sum of hours based on the difference between time present in same colums?

| date | time |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-11-08 | 08:25:57 |
| 2017-11-08 | 12:31:59 |
| 2017-11-08 | 13:28:42 |
| 2017-11-08 | 17:34:13 |
| 2017-11-09 | 08:28:08 |
| 2017-11-09 | 12:31:15 |
| 2017-11-09 | 13:20:13 |

I can get separate data for enditime and startime with this query:

```
SELECT MAX(time) AS "endtime",
       MIN(time) AS "startime",
       MAX(time)-MIN(time) as "totalneedtocalculatepause"
WHERE (date = '2017-11-08'::date )
FROM history ts
```

but startpause and endpause are missing:

| endtime | startime | totalneedtocalculatepause |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17:34:13 | 08:25:57 | 09:08:16 |

The correct sequence should be:

```
day         startpause   starttime    endtime     endpause
2017-11-08: (12:31:59 - 08:25:57) + (17:34:13 - 13:28:42)
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the understanding that your records are coupled and consecutive values represent start-end periods, you can use a `ROW_NUMBER` function, divided by 2, and ceiled, to identify the couples (partitions). Then use your query, while partitioning on the new generated column.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CEIL((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY time)+1)/2) AS rn 
    FROM history
)
SELECT MAX(time) AS "endtime",
       MIN(time) AS "startime",
       CAST(MAX(time)-MIN(time) AS time) AS "totalneedtocalculatepause"
FROM cte
WHERE (date = '2017-11-08'::date)
GROUP BY rn
```

"**Output**":

| endtime | startime | totalneedtocalculatepause |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12:31:59 | 08:25:57 | 04:06:02 |
| 17:34:13 | 13:28:42 | 04:05:31 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tohb9gRig2mk17J4aDznc9/0).

---

If you want the overall summary, you can apply a further aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CEIL((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY time)+1)/2) AS rn 
    FROM history
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT MAX(time) AS "endtime",
           MIN(time) AS "startime",
           CAST(MAX(time)-MIN(time) AS time) AS "totalneedtocalculatepause"
    FROM cte
    WHERE (date = '2017-11-08'::date)
    GROUP BY rn
)
SELECT MAX(endtime) AS "endtime",
       MIN(startime) AS "startime",
       CAST(SUM(totalneedtocalculatepause) AS TIME) AS "totalneedtocalculatepause"
FROM cte2
```

"**Output**":

| endtime | startime | totalneedtocalculatepause |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17:34:13 | 08:25:57 | 08:11:33 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tohb9gRig2mk17J4aDznc9/1).

Comment: Nice solution, but how would you manage multiple days as i t always use single day even without WHERE (date = '2017-11-08'::date) ?

Comment: Play with the linked fiddle and change it to reflect this scenario. Maybe this use case is directly addressed or requires small changes to work under that circumstances. If it's needed, send it here updated with the new data and output.

Answer (score 2):

What about lag instead of ceil?
i.e. if not all rows are pairs?

I've edited the fiddle to manage more days:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jsHiga6b2BmgmacrsadkCF/0

```
SELECT *, lag(time) OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY time) AS "starttime"  
    FROM history;
```

First split time columns

```
WITH cte AS (

  SELECT *, lag(time) OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY time) AS "starttime"  
    FROM history
)
SELECT 
       CAST("time"-"starttime" AS time) AS "segment"
FROM cte
WHERE (date >= '2017-11-08'   AND date <  '2017-12-09'      )
group by date, time,starttime
;
```

Then calculate single segments of time.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, lag(time) OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY time) AS "starttime"  
    FROM history
), cte2 AS (
    select 
    CAST("time"-"starttime" AS time) AS "segment"
    FROM cte
WHERE (date >= '2017-11-08'   AND date <  '2017-12-08'      )
    group by date, time,starttime
)
SELECT        
       CAST(SUM(segment) AS TIME) AS "total"
       
       
FROM cte2
where segment > interval '1 hour';
```

Then get totals, to count the pause I expect that this will not be more than 1 hour so excluding lesser intervals should give you the correct total.